# PayPal API: Sandbox Notifications on Completed

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm setting up a service using the WordPress platform that handles both one-time and recurring payments using the PayPal API. My initial test of the one-time system garnered notifications in both my Buyer and Faciliator accounts. Now, however, when testing either one-time or recurring payments, I get no notifications. The transaction shows completed, but nothing appears in the PayPal Developer site's Sandbox notifications area. Here's what the service returns from the API curl execution:

```
array(6) {
  ["transactionId"]=>
  string(17) "2RH00821X8505444L"
  ["transactionStatus"]=>
  string(9) "COMPLETED"
  ["receiver"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["amount"]=>
    string(6) "100.00"
    ["email"]=>
    string(32) "dev-buyer@blueinkalchemy.com"
    ["primary"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["invoiceId"]=>
    string(25) "1299-2017-05-12T17:53:56Z"
    ["paymentType"]=>
    string(7) "SERVICE"
    ["accountId"]=>
    string(13) "4UY5S5W59FHN4"
  }
  ["pendingRefund"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["senderTransactionId"]=>
  string(17) "3E141636AX513663W"
  ["senderTransactionStatus"]=>
  string(9) "COMPLETED"
}
```

Is there a bug or delay involved with Sandbox notifications? Have I missed setting a flag in my API call?

Comment: What do you use for notifications? Email or IPN?

Comment: The first notifications I got were emails in my "Sandbox emails and SMS notifications". I haven't gotten anything there since despite the code listed above.